# Checar se padrão é seguido, JSON e PHP

Tags: php, json

Existe um pequeno padrão de requisição com vários parametros, mas eu vou simplifica-lo desta forma:

```
$parametrosdBase = array('nome' => false, 'codigo' => 83474, etc..
```

Eu recebo uma string em formato JSON que teoricamente deve **CONTER** esses parametros, ou seja ela tem que ter todos aqueles parametros que eu mostrei na array acima.

Sim eu poderia simplesmente checar se cada parametro existe manualmente mas como é em larga escala eu gostaria de uma função que fizesse isso automaticamente.

obs: o parametro pode até estar `vazio, false, 0` o importante é ele **existir**.

Comment: Quer apenas verificar se a string recebida é um JSON?

Comment: @mauriciocaserta Oi, não, é para checar se os parametros foram seguidos.

Comment: Estes parametros estão no level root do json?

Comment: Você quer comparar as chaves do `$parametrosdBase` com as chaves do json ou você também quer comparar os valores de $parametrosdBase com os valores dentro do json?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Oi, talvez eu tenha usado as palavras erradas, não é para comparar valores. é assim: Eu tenho aquela array de base, e eu quero verificar em uma string de formato JSON se todos os parametros da array de base também estão presentes na string codificada, independentemente se elas estão vazias, false, 0 etc..

Comment: Acho que ela quer verificar se existem as chaves 'nome', 'codigo' dentro do array?

Comment: Elaine eu não afirmei que era comparar valores, eu perguntei se eram valores e chaves ou apenas chaves, vou supor que seja as chaves que você necessita, vou formular uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se com parametros, você quer dizer "chaves" então você pode fazer usando `array_keys` que irá pegar as chaves nome, codigo, etc da variável `$parametrosdBase` e usaremos o `array_key_exists` pra verificar se a chave existe (já que você disse que os valores podem ser vazio, false suponho que possam ser `null` também).

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$parametrosdBase = array('nome' => false, 'codigo' => 83474);

$json = json_decode('{"nome": "João", "codigo": false, "foo": "hello" }', true);

$chaves = array_keys($parametrosdBase);

$error = null;

foreach ($chaves as $value) {
    if (false === array_key_exists($json[$value])) {
        $error = 'Parametro "' . $value . '" não encontrado';
        break;
    }
}

if ($error) {
    echo $error;
} else {
    echo 'Todos parametros da base encontrados!';
}
```

### isset vs array_key_exists

Eu troquei o `isset` por `array_key_exists`, pois se tiver algum **valor** com `null`, então ele irá dar `false` acaso use `isset`, mesmo que a chave exista.

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => null, 'second' => 4);

// Retorna false
isset($search_array['first']);

// Retorna true
array_key_exists('first', $search_array);
```

### O que são chaves em uma array

Note que estes parâmetros aos quais se referem geralmente são chamados de "chaves" ou keys (em inglês), veja:

PHP:

```
array('nome'                  => 'João');
        ^---Isto é uma chave       ^-----Isto é um valor de uma chave
```

Json:

```
{'nome':                     'João'};
    ^---Isto é uma chave       ^-----Isto é um valor de uma chave
```

Comment: Ora, essas coisinhas são chamadas chaves? não sabia, aprendi algo e resolvi problemas, thank uuuu

Comment: @Elaine atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente o seguinte codigo:

```
$entrada = json_decode( $json, true );
$params = array( ... );
$intersecao = array_intersect_assoc( $entrada, $params );
$sucesso = count( $intersecao ) == count( $params );
```